# grails, loading domain from db when fields contains null causes setters to fail

Tags: grails, grails-orm

This problem is about some fields that are declared double and often is null in the database.
Using findAllBy to receive a list then fails if some of the fields are null.
I tried with changing the type to Double but then I get problems when I do arithmetics on them. If the value is null the Double can't decide which converter it should use.
I don't know if there is any way to convert nulls in the domain before they are set.
Example of error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.buffer.ProdBuffer.makeInquiry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `Double` in your entities/domains; unless you have a `nullable: false` constraint at work, even then it's a good practice, nonetheless.

However, you need to handle `null` by yourself in your calculations, probably by making that 0 or 1, you know it better. For more suggestions, post the code snippet.

Comment: I followed your recommendation and changed all double-fields to Double and took care of the nulls where they possibly could appear and finally I got it to work. Thanks.